# Regresar un nuevo arreglo de areglos

Tags: javascript, array, foreach

Tengo un arreglo de arreglos y necesito generar un nuevo arreglo como está en el ejemplo de resul en cada elemento se guardan las letras que estan en la misma posicion de los arreglos de letras.

```
const Entrada = [[a, z, c], [j, b, d], [a, c, d]  ]                             
const SalidaEsperada = [[a, j, a ],[z, b, c], [c, d, d]]
```

Intente iterarlos con un `forEach` ¡ pero me regresa `undefined`!

```
const result= [ ];                    

Entrada.forEach((letra, index)  =>  {
    result.push(letra[index])    
} )
```

Alguna sugerencia

Comment: Listo ya quedo agregado !

Answer (score 1):

La forma en que yo lo haría seria con `reduce`

```js
let result = [];
Entrada = [['a', 'z', 'c'], ['j', 'b', 'd']]
result = Entrada.reduce((act, sgt, i) => {
    i == 0 ? act = sgt.map(x => [x]) : sgt.forEach((x, i) => act[i].push(x))
    return act
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

O lo puedes hacer de una manera mas entendible, seria con un doble `for` invertido

```js
let result = [];
Entrada = [['a', 'z', 'c'], ['j', 'b', 'd']]
for(let i=0; i<Entrada[0].length; i++) {
  result.push([])
  for(let j=0; j<Entrada.length; j++) {
    result[i].push(Entrada[j][i])
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa `const result= [ ];` (no `resul` para comenzar). Pero el resultado no llegara a lo que deseas. Asumiendo que Entrada es un array de 2 entradas con igual numero de elementos (2xN):

```
const Entrada = [[a, z, c], [j, b, d]]                               
const SalidaEsperada = [[a, j],[z, b], [c, d]]
const result = Entrada[0].map(function(letra,index){
  return [Entrada[0][index],Entrada[1][index]]
})
```

https://codepen.io/fraigo/pen/RwrOKqz?editors=1111